# Read out Alarm volume

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I try to read out the Alarm volume the following way, but I always get wrong values. The ringer volume is always correct!! 
That happens on every Smartphone, HTC, Samsung, Sony and even on the virtual device. What could be the problem?

```
private AudioManager amanager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    amanager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

}



int volume = 3;
int alarm = 3;

try{
    volume = amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
    alarm = amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
    Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!", "Activity!!,  Volume ringer: " + volume + " Vol Alarm: " + alarm);

}catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting wrong values for the ringer volume. The method `getStreamVolume (int streamType)` gets an `int` and returns `int`. When you write:

```
alarm = amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
```

you're actually getting the volume of the alarm (lets say it is X), and then passing to `alarm` the value `alarm = amanager.getStreamVolume(X);`

so the result is unexpected.
change the values of `volume` and `alarm` to -

```
volume = amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
alarm = amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```